# How to use Markdown to display timeline?

Tags: markdown, hexo

I would like to display timeline information using `markdown`, how to do?

By the way, I want to make it in `hexo`.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Markdown [isn't intended to support this kind of thing](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> Markdown’s syntax is intended for one purpose: to be used as a format for *writing* for the web.
>
> …
>
> Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags.

You could create an image and [include a link to it in your Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img). Alternatively, if you have some method for generating these visuals in HTML you could [use those tags directly](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html).

Some implementations of Markdown add features that aren't present in the original version, for example tables. I'm not aware of any that display timelines.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [hexo-tag-mdline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hexo-tag-mdline) plugin, https://www.npmjs.com/package/hexo-tag-mdline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [markline](https://github.com/hotoo/markline) which is a timeline extension to markdown.

Answer (score 0):

[mermaid](https://mermaid.js.org/intro/) can be used to create chart. It has 'timeline' plot. [Here](https://github.blog/2022-02-14-include-diagrams-markdown-files-mermaid/) is how you can implement it in markdown (very simple). That's being said, I find it hard to control the appearance.

```
:::mermaid
timeline
    title History of Social Media Platform
    2002 : LinkedIn
    2004 : Facebook
         : Google
    2005 : Youtube
    2006 : Twitter
:::
```

Answer (score 0):

I found amazing markdown timeline maker.

Below are the markdown file.

```
title: My timeline example
description: Hello, world!

#Travel: blue
#Education: #ab5

group Travel #Travel
Jan 2019: The Bahamas [Bahamas](location) #Travel
endGroup

section Other stuff
August 2020 - now: Getting my degree #Education
endSection
```

https://github.com/mark-when/markwhen

[image]

Amazingly, we can also install it as VSCode Extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Markwhen.markwhen